# Navigation Bar Custom DropShadow in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to apply a custom drop shadow to `NavigationView` with White Background.

I did try with `UINavigationBar.appearance()` but it didn't work in the SwiftUI Views.

[image]

I am looking for this kind of shadow with custom color and radius.

Has anyone faced any issue in it or done it before.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why UINavigationBarAppearance wasn't working for you.

I was able to do this for SwiftUI NavigationViews using the UINavigationBarAppearance() configurations, like this:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.shadowColor = nil // or a custom tint color
appearance.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "shadow")
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
```

Here's a sample image you could use to get something similar to what your image shows. To apply a custom tint, use the `shadowColor` property above. To get a custom radius, you'd need to modify the shadow image.

[image: Shadow Image]

Here's an example of what the SwiftUI NavigationView looks like when I do this.

[image: Result]

Note that the UINavigationBarAppearance settings must be applied before the NavigationView is created. Otherwise, the settings won't take effect.

Comment: testing on iOS 16, even adding backgroundColor , for ex to White. at the beginning kind shows the background of the app so is translucent, when scrolling down it becomes white at the navigation bar, then when pushing to another view, it puts the shadow image below the --inline title --.. kinda duplicates it :/ weird